# How to have the bot send a message every time a user loses a specific role in a set channel

Tags: discord.py, pycord

I'm trying to have the bot send a message every time someone loses the Dark Role. I'm somewhat new to discord.py but still, know quite a few things.

This is my code:

````
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    rolel = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name='Dark Clan')
    channell = discord.utils.get(after.guild.channels, name='-dark-clan')
    if rolel in after.roles:
        await channell.send(f"{after.mention} left the clan.")```
````